# django redirect not working as expected

Tags: django

I have a view that either displays a form or a 'thank you' page (if the form submission was successful). I am using redirect with a url that I have tested working to display the thank-you page.

```
def form8(request):
    form = UserInfoForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/sjwork/thanks')
    return render(request, 'form8.html', {'form': form})
```

However, when the form is successfully submitted django give the error:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /sjwork/form8
Could not import views. Error was: No module named views
```

As said, I can go to localhost:8000/sjwork/thanks directly and it displays the thank-you page. According to documentation I can use a hard-coded url like this. I tried alternatives, too (giving the view, using a full url like http://google.com) - nothing works. I must be missing something basic here. Would appreciate if someone can explain what is going on here. Thanks.

The app 'sjwork' has the following in its urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', 'views.home', name='home'),
url(r'^thanks$', 'sjwork.views.thanks'),
url(r'^form8$', 'sjwork.views.form8', name='form8'),
```

whereas the project urls.py contains:

```
url(r'^sjwork/', include('formtest.sjwork.urls')),
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to post your url patterns, in addition to the provided view.

Comment: The 'app' has the following in the urlpatters in its urls.py:

Comment: `Could not import views. Error was: No module named views`. Fix that and try again.

Comment: See the problem is I cannot make any sense of the error message in this case. I know this is related to the redirect line. If I replace the redirect line with `render(request, 'thanks.html')` everything works fine.

Comment: Don't use hardcoded url its a bad approach, use url reverse technique. redirect(reverse('thanks')). Also i assume the problem is with this `url(r'^$', 'views.home', name='home')` changed it to `url(r'^$', 'sjwork.views.home', name='home')` ??

Comment: Thank you very much! It was the problem of having `views.home` instead of `sjwork.views.home`. Once that was done, all the methods mentioned in the documentation works! Would you kindly explain why I need to include the app prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like error is related to this pattern.

```
url(r'^$', 'views.home', name='home'),
```

Try removing it and try again.
Also, Could you include your import statements in your question.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, as Aamir noted, including app prefix 'sjwork' solved the problem. But I am still puzzled why django had to look at that particular urlpattern.

Comment: Your welcome. I would suggest not to hard code the references to view functions instead try to import them and refer the method object directly. This would give you better flexibility and save you from a lot of hassle.